# wcf and knockout.js combine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, architecture, knockout.js

I got my datalayer, business layer ready. Now i want to to implement service layer.
I do not want to implement this layer in wcf ria services. Is there any other way to implement this layer in such a way using wcf, so that I get my model through wcf using js.
For example I have my domain 'Person'. (In domain project). Then in my 'PersonRespository' has 
InsertPerson, GetPerson etc. to get and store the 'Person' in database.

Now I want to use asp.net mvc to show the person detais.

So next two layer will be Presentation Layer and service layer and manipulate data on client side using knockout.js and I am stuck on following issues.

1. Where will be mine Presentation layer will live. I am using asp.net mvc so It should be in model folder of mvc application, Is it wise to copy the same code class (Person) to model folder as well from domain model. Event when they are same.
2. How I will be able to get 'Person' model class in javascript and able to update it from javascript to database as well.

Is my architecture style is of enterprise level or i am missing something.

Any point to tutorial will be helpful.

If you have any further questions please let me know.

Thanks,

Daljit

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:

No you should not be repeating your code. There is talk about this in the DRY (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principals of development.

Question 2:

It is recommended that you serialize your model using a json serializer and send it to your UI. It will be updated etc, and then sent back to the services. Google MVVM pattern in javascript to see how this is done. KnockoutJs is a great start in achieving what you want. Its probably best to check out some examples done in knockoutjs to see what is going on. There are also many examples in MVVM for WPF that might help understanding the pattern at a higher level. I would recommend seeing codeproject.com for indepth MVVM examples.

As far as your layers go, you have many options, but a generic recommendation would be:

1) Presentation must be triggered through MVVM bindings, ie if the binding updates, the UI will then update itself.
2) the asp.net side of things should only update the models when sending updates via ajax to the UI. (not everything needs to be sent via ajax, im not saying that. When it does, it shouldn't also send extra html or js to put in the page).
3) Your models should really come from asp.net to the html page. (this will make things easier later, as the page will only be updated via asp.net models and you won't get items coming from multiple domains, which ends up being a nuisance.
4) Your asp.net site should provide a wrapper for your WCF service, and can foward calls to WCF.

OR

If you didn't want to wrap WCF with asp.net and needed your UI to communicate directly via ajax to WCF (should be a rarer usecase like doing an igoogle like page with widgets, or maybe mobile development with no asp.net interaction, ie full js app) Then you can investigate CORS as an option to go from JS to WCF and JS to asp.net (This is of a hard difficulty, easy to program, hard to get working for WCF as there is very very low documentation on it for in my case non IIS hosted WCF). See this page for information: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: thanks for reply, i was thinking of copy domain model to models of asp.net mvc, because of mvvm

Comment: Your MVVM models might be similar to your data access layer models however I think in time they will end up different. The view-models will end up having displayish logic and interactions that will/should end up different to more pure data access layer models.